# CActiveDataProvider not resolving params in criteria

Tags: php, yii

I'm following along with [Agile Web Application Development with Yii 1.1 and PHP5](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHcQFjAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Web-Application-Development-PHP5/dp/1847199585&ei=sZykT9H9EeOviQLiiMzqAg&usg=AFQjCNHsc34PiJIVJFk-7dc-V6uJw_GqEg&sig2=G5QQV381maBljonqIhNz5g), working on the "TrackStar" project.  For the life of me I can't understand where my problem is.
I'm getting the Exception:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_issue` `t` WHERE project_id=:projectId

It appears (to this noob's interpretation) that the params in my CActiveDataProvider is some how not resolving in the criteria as in the view:

```
(in /protected/controllers/ProjectController.php)

55         public function actionView()
56         {
57             $issueDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Issue', array(
58                 'criteria' => array(
59                     'condition' => 'project_id=:projectId',
60                     'params' => array(':projectId=' => $this->loadModel()->id),
61                 ),
62                 'pagination' => array( 
63                     'pageSize' => 1,
64                 ),      
65             )); 
66             $this->render('view',array(
67                     'model'=>$this->loadModel(),
68                     'issueDataProvider' => $issueDataProvider,
69             ));
70         }
```

I checked my code against a [github repo](https://github.com/jefftulsa/TrackStar/tree/master/trackstar) and I couldn't find any differences anywhere.
Is there something straightforward I'm missing here without having to post all of my code (and have somebody actually look through it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you have an error in params of your criteria.  (`=` after  :projectId). 
Right statement is

```
   'params' => array(':projectId' => $this->loadModel()->id),
```

Params array is list of query parameter values indexed by parameter placeholders. For example, array(':name'=>'Dan', ':age'=>'31').

Comment: geez... a whole day on that.  Thank you.. :)